# What are the cases in which a loop cannot be unrolled?

Tags: c, cuda, opencl

What are the cases in which a loop cannot be unrolled? I've been reading a paper which shows a loop that it says is not able to be unrolled. I cannot actually post the specific code as it is private, however, I am wondering if there is something obvious I am missing in regards to not being able to unroll.

Thanks in advance. If there's any other info that I can try to provide, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure there are any cases of loops that *cannot* be unrolled, at least partially. Even an infinite loop can be transformed to a loop whose body is replicated N times. There may well be cases of loops where unrolling isn't going to do any good or is too difficult.

Comment: There could be many reasons, it will depend on the tool chain. Some compiler can give indications (may require additional warning or reporting flags) as to why loop unrolling didn't take place. Two I have seen were "not an innermost loop" and "unstructured control flow inside loop".

Answer (score 3):

well you can't unroll a loop with any type of recursion in it because it could be infinitely long, also you cant unroll an infinite loop or one with some kind of method for breaking out that isn't incremental

recursion:

```
 method(int x){
 if(x > 0)
     return 0;
 else
     return method(x-1);
```

infinite loop:

```
 while(true){
 ...
 if(some condition)
     break;
 }
```

last one:

```
 boolean somevar = true;

 while(somevar){
 ...
 if(some condition)
      somevar = false;
 }
```

Comment: The first case is not a loop. There can be no unrolling.

Comment: You **can** unroll a loop with recursion but only to some level. Some compilers allows you to change the unrolled level